# Custom radio buttons to show/hide content

Tags: html, css, email, radio-button

I am trying to build a interactive email content block that would show or hide content based on the selection. It worked before I tried to customize the label. It stopped working after I wrapped the input and label inside a div. I think it could be throwing my selectors off but I am not sure how remedy the problem.

```css
.custom-radios input[type="radio"] + label span img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"]#red + label span {
  background-color: red;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"]#blue + label span {
  background-color: blue;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"]#green + label span {
  background-color: green;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"]#orange + label span {
  background-color: orange;
}
.custom-radios input[type="radio"]:checked + label span img {
  opacity: 1;
}


    #red{
    display: none
    }
    #blue{
        display: none
    }
    #green{
        display: none
    }
    #orange{
        display: none
    }
    input[type="red"]:checked ~ #red {
    display: block
    }

    input[value="blue"]:checked ~ #blue {
        display: block;
    }

    input[value="green"]:checked ~ #green {
        display: block;
    }

    input[value="orange"]:checked ~ #orange {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="custom-radios">

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="red">
    <label for="red">
      <span>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" value="blue">
    <label for="blue">
      <span>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="green">
    <label for="green">
      <span>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="orange" name="color" value="orange">
    <label for="orange">
      <span>
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="spacer" style="line-height:26px;height:26px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">&nbsp;</div>

<p style="margin:0;" id="red">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/580x200/FF0000/FFFFFF" width="580" alt="" style="width:100%;height:auto;max-width:580px;" />
</p>
<p style="margin:0;" id="blue">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/580x200/0000FF/FFFFFF" width="580" alt="" style="width:100%;height:auto;max-width:580px;" />
</p>
<p style="margin:0;" id="green">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/580x200/00FF00/FFFFFF" width="580" alt="" style="width:100%;height:auto;max-width:580px;" />
</p>
<p style="margin:0;" id="orange">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/580x200/FFA500/FFFFFF" width="580" alt="" style="width:100%;height:auto;max-width:580px;" />
</p>

<div class="spacer" style="line-height:26px;height:26px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

Comment: It's broken because selector `a ~ b` means `b` placed after `a` in the same parent. Your `#red`, `#blue`, etc, belongs to a different parent than `input[...]:checked`. Check the [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) from w3schools, it may help you.

Comment: Hi Leo I have been at this all day and still havent been able to solve this. but when i wrapped the image part in a div and changed 
```input[type="red"]:checked ~ #red {
    display: block
    }``` 
to 
```input[type="red"]:checked ~ div #red {
    display: block
    }```
it worked. but when i wrap the radio part in a div, it broke again

Answer (score 0):

I think selectors may be a weak point for you, again, I encourage you to check the [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) from w3school.

Anyways, I made a simplified version, as similar as I could to you current structure, so you can see it working.

```css
.hidden_input {
  display: none;
}

#red_input+label>span {
  background-color: red;
}

#blue_input+label>span {
  background-color: blue;
}

label>span>img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.hidden_input:checked+label>span>img {
  opacity: 1;
}

#red_content,
#blue_content {
  display: none;
}

#red_input:checked~#red_content,
#blue_input:checked~#blue_content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-radios">
  <input type="radio" id="red_input" class="hidden_input" name="color" value="red">
  <label for="red_input">
    <span>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg"/>
    </span>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="blue_input" class="hidden_input" name="color" value="blue">
  <label for="blue_input">
    <span>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg"/>
    </span>
  </label>

  <div class="spacer" style="line-height:26px;height:26px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">&nbsp;</div>

  <p style="margin:0;" id="red_content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/580x200/FF0000/FFFFFF" width="580" style="width:100%;height:auto;max-width:580px;" />
  </p>
  <p style="margin:0;" id="blue_content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/580x200/0000FF/FFFFFF" width="580" style="width:100%;height:auto;max-width:580px;" />
  </p>
</div>
```

You can also play and place elements wherever you want in your HTML code, and then set their position with `grid` (it's just another option).